# Mocking Inherited Classes with Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sockets, mocking, jestjs

I am extending [net.Socket](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket). In doing so, I am overriding the connect method as follows.

```
class ENIP extends Socket {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            session: { id: null, establishing: false, established: false },
            error: { code: null, msg: null }
        };
    }

    connect(IP_ADDR) {
        const { registerSession } = encapsulation; //returns a buffer to send

        this.state.session.establishing = true;

        return new Promise(resolve => {
            super.connect(EIP_PORT, IP_ADDR, () => { // This is what i want to mock -> super.connect
                this.state.session.establishing = false;

                this.write(registerSession());
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I want to mock the underlying **Socket** class so that I can simulate `super.connect`.  Having viewed Facebook's [docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/es6-class-mocks.html) on the matter, I am unsure on how to proceed with developing tests for this class as all methods will extend `super.someMethodToMock`.  Does anyone know an approach I should take? Please let me know if there are *any* clarifying details I can provide.

Comment: Don't use inheritance.

Comment: I think inheritance makes the solution much cleaner.

Comment: But more difficult to test. The cleaner the code, the easier to test, to paraphrase Uncle Bob, the author of clean code and perhaps the foremost advocate of TDD ;)

Comment: Besides, delegation in JavaScript is so trivial, requiring merely a single line of code in this case, that you would do well to use dependency injection. One reason you might use inheritance would be if you're passing it to an API that does instance of tests. There are ways around that, but if you're doing the tests yourself then you're writing bad JavaScript

Comment: Anyway, if you don't want to change your code, the simplest solution would be to export a higher-order class, at class factory if you will, in addition to your current API, that you might pass in the class being extended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest mock method of base ES6 class (super method) when testing extended class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65391369/jest-mock-method-of-base-es6-class-super-method-when-testing-extended-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to create mock methods on `Socket.prototype`.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
import { Socket } from 'net';

const EIP_PORT = 3000;
const encapsulation = {
  registerSession() {
    return 'session';
  },
};

export class ENIP extends Socket {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      session: { id: null, establishing: false, established: false },
      error: { code: null, msg: null },
    };
  }

  connect(IP_ADDR) {
    const { registerSession } = encapsulation;
    this.state.session.establishing = true;

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      super.connect(EIP_PORT, IP_ADDR, () => {
        this.state.session.establishing = false;
        this.write(registerSession());
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import { ENIP } from './';
import { Socket } from 'net';

describe('ENIP', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  describe('#connect', () => {
    it('should pass', async () => {
      const writeSpy = jest.spyOn(Socket.prototype, 'write').mockImplementation();
      const connectSpy = jest.spyOn(Socket.prototype, 'connect').mockImplementationOnce((port, addr, callback) => {
        callback();
      });
      const enip = new ENIP();
      await enip.connect('localhost');
      expect(writeSpy).toBeCalledWith('session');
      expect(connectSpy).toBeCalledWith(3000, 'localhost', expect.any(Function));
    });
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/48888509/index.test.jsx (10.43s)
  ENIP
    #connect
      ✓ should pass (7ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.jsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.357s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/48888509