# JEST | Assert a function was called inside addEventListener callback

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the following function:

### Code to test

```
export default function main() {
    const createAndAppendPTag = () => {
        const p = document.createElement('p');
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    };

    window.document.addEventListener('click', () => {
        createAndAppendPTag();
    });
}
```

**The question is: How can I assert using Jest that `createAndAppendPTag` was called upon a document click event ?**

---

### Jest

This is what I tried, but can't seem to make the test pass:

```
import main from './main'

window.document.addEventListener = jest.fn();
const createAndAppendPTag = jest.fn();

describe('Main', () => {
    const documentClickEvent = new Event('click');

    test('appends p tag to the document', () => {
        // dispatching event before and after invoking `main` to be sure
        window.document.dispatchEvent(documentClickEvent);

        main();

        window.document.dispatchEvent(documentClickEvent);

        expect(window.document.addEventListener).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, 'click', () => {});
        expect(createAndAppendPTag).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

### Terminal

This results in the following:

```sh
  Main › appends p tag to the document
    
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(n, ...expected)
    
n: 1
Expected: "click", [Function anonymous]
    
Number of calls: 0
    
5   | main();
6   | window.document.dispatchEvent(documentClickEvent);
> 7 | expect(window.document.addEventListener).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, 'click', () => {});
*   |                                          ^
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `createAndAppendPTag` is private to main, so you don't have visibility to it while testing. Can you simply test for the side effect directly (`p` was added to the body)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @terrymorse, I've been trying to do so for the past hour or so with no luck, seems I need to ask another question later about querying the dom in a test because I'm getting empty body, until then maybe someone can provide another suggestion/solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran this simplified test to check for the side effect (`p` element was appended to body):

`main.js`

```js
export default function main() {
  const createAndAppendPTag = () => {
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  };

  window.document.addEventListener('click', () => {
    createAndAppendPTag();
  });
}
```

`main.test.js`

```js
import main from `../main.js`;

it('"main" listener appends "P" to body upon click', () => {
  // add listener
  main();

  // clear body contents
  document.body.innerHTML = "";

  // dispatch click event to listener
  const addEvt = new Event('click');
  document.dispatchEvent(addEvt);

  // check for existence of "P" element
  const bodyEl = document.body.firstChild;
  expect(bodyEl).not.toEqual(null);
  expect(bodyEl.tagName).toBe('P');
  document.body.innerHTML = "";
});
```

It passed:

```
  ✓ "main" listener appends "P" to body upon click (2 ms)
```

Comment: Thank you Terry, as you suggested, I should assert for the side effect in such cases. Marking this as the correct answer (just the `typeof bodyEl` is not needed imo since everything in JS is an object :D)

Comment: @SamLahm Well, not *everything* in JS is an object. There's `string`, `number`, `boolean`, and `undefined`, to name a few. Although `null` is an object, which is a problem. So this test is better: `expect(bodyEl).not.toEqual(null)` (I'll change the answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to create mocks for `window.document.addEventListener()`, `document.createElement()` and `document.body.appendChild()` methods.

Since the `createAndAppendPTag` function is private, you cannot spy/mock it, but you can indirectly determine whether it is called by asserting its internal method.

E.g. using `"jest": "^26.6.3"`:

`main.js`:

```js
export default function main() {
  const createAndAppendPTag = () => {
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  };

  window.document.addEventListener('click', () => {
    createAndAppendPTag();
  });
}
```

`main.test.js`:

```js
import main from './main';

describe('65451115', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    const createElementSpy = jest.spyOn(document, 'createElement').mockReturnValue('fake p');
    const appendChildSpy = jest.spyOn(document.body, 'appendChild').mockReturnValue();
    const addEventListenerSpy = jest
      .spyOn(window.document, 'addEventListener')
      .mockImplementationOnce((event, handler) => {
        handler();
      });
    main();
    expect(addEventListenerSpy).toBeCalledWith('click', expect.any(Function));
    expect(createElementSpy).toBeCalledWith('p');
    expect(appendChildSpy).toBeCalledWith('fake p');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65451115/main.test.js (10.621 s)
  65451115
    ✓ should pass (4 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 main.js  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        16.536 s
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Any chance I can assert that `createAndAppendPTag` was called ? (even if I have to change the source code)

Comment: @SamLahm You need to expose it, so that you can install spy or mock it. Then you can assert it was called or not.

Comment: [Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65391369/jest-mock-method-of-base-es6-class-super-method-when-testing-extended-class/65392037#comment115609679_65392037) some commentary on whether this is good practice might be helpful. You're mocking an interface you don't own, and testing implementation rather than behaviour. Exposing an implementation detail just to mock it for a test is worse still.